# Activation of network connection failed HP Probook 650 G1

Tags: networking, connection

I have a HP ProBook 650 G1 with a bootable USB stick with Ubuntu 20.04.2. Wi-Fi works, but the ethernet connection gives periodically:

> Activation of network connection failed.

The ethernet port is visible as `ep0s25`. It does not make a difference if the port is set as DHCP or as a fixed IP address. When this PC boots from its normal drive with Windows, then the ethernet port functions OK.

I tried:

- Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS 32 bit, same result.
- Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS, same result.
- Updated BIOS to version 01.50 of 24-02-2020, same result.

Please find some information below, has anyone a suggestion.

```
user@user-HP-ProBook-650-G1:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal

user@user-HP-ProBook-650-G1:~$ cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "model name"
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4210M CPU @ 2.60GHz

user@user-HP-ProBook-650-G1:~$ sudo dmesg | grep eth
[    2.611257] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: (PCI Express:2.5GT/s:Width x1) fc:3f:db:8c:ef:9e
[    2.611259] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
[    2.611309] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: MAC: 11, PHY: 12, PBA No: FFFFFF-0FF
[    2.612228] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 enp0s25: renamed from eth0

user@user-HP-ProBook-650-G1:~$ sudo lshw -c network
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection I217-V
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: enp0s25
       version: 04
       serial: fc:3f:db:8c:ef:9e
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k duplex=full firmware=0.12-3 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:30 memory:d0700000-d071ffff memory:d073f000-d073ffff ioport:3080(size=32)
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 00
       serial: c8:ff:28:87:d6:12
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.271 (r587334) ip=192.168.178.241 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:18 memory:d0500000-d0503fff

user@user-HP-ProBook-650-G1:~$ sudo ifconfig
enp0s25: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::fcb3:b39:3b10:f967  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether fc:3f:db:8c:ef:9e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 3  bytes 192 (192.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 221  bytes 39600 (39.6 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 20  memory 0xd0700000-d0720000  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 877  bytes 87656 (87.6 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 877  bytes 87656 (87.6 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlo1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.178.241  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.178.255
        inet6 2a02:a210:2d00:6000:2b4a:ba1f:2712:d1c3  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 2a02:a210:2d00:6000:b1a:c9db:2856:5ac8  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::e3ca:8ab8:5d67:9b87  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether c8:ff:28:87:d6:12  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 170753  bytes 254393767 (254.3 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 7936
        TX packets 70797  bytes 6377017 (6.3 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 18

user@user-HP-ProBook-650-G1:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I217-V (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d4)
00:1c.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #7 (rev d4)
00:1c.7 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #8 (rev d4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM87 Express LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5227 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
```

A remarkable issue is that after a reboot, network functions sometimes but mostly not. Here follows a part of the result of journalctl -f.

```
    monteur@monteur-HP-ProBook-650-G1:~$ journalctl -f
-- Logs begin at Thu 2021-02-11 16:08:46 CET. --
Feb 18 15:41:55 monteur-HP-ProBook-650-G1 systemd[889]: gnome-launched-x-terminal-emulator-1982.scope: Succeeded.
Feb 18 15:41:58 monteur-HP-ProBook-650-G1 NetworkManager[717]: <info>  [1613659318.1779] policy: auto-activating connection 'Wired connection 1' (561d04b9-8c3a-36e4-aff4-86c737eb7cab)
Feb 18 15:41:58 monteur-HP-ProBook-650-G1 NetworkManager[717]: <info>  [1613659318.1784] device (enp0s25): Activation: starting connection 'Wired connection 1' (561d04b9-8c3a-36e4-aff4-86c737eb7cab)
Feb 18 15:41:58 monteur-HP-ProBook-650-G1 NetworkManager[717]: <info>  [1613659318.1786] device (enp0s25): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 18 15:41:58 monteur-HP-ProBook-650-G1 NetworkManager[717]: <info>  [1613659318.1791] device (enp0s25): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 18 15:41:58 monteur-HP-ProBook-650-G1 NetworkManager[717]: <info>  [1613659318.1799] device (enp0s25): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 18 15:41:58 monteur-HP-ProBook-650-G1 NetworkManager[717]: <info>  [1613659318.1802] dhcp4 (enp0s25): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Feb 18 15:41:58 monteur-HP-ProBook-650-G1 avahi-daemon[712]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface enp0s25.IPv6 with address fe80::b343:1d23:df15:7b48.
Feb 18 15:41:58 monteur-HP-ProBook-650-G1 avahi-daemon[712]: New relevant interface enp0s25.IPv6 for mDNS.
Feb 18 15:41:58 monteur-HP-ProBook-650-G1 avahi-daemon[712]: Registering new address record for fe80::b343:1d23:df15:7b48 on enp0s25.*.
Feb 18 15:42:08 monteur-HP-ProBook-650-G1 systemd-resolved[526]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Feb 18 15:42:08 monteur-HP-ProBook-650-G1 systemd-resolved[526]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Feb 18 15:42:08 monteur-HP-ProBook-650-G1 systemd-resolved[526]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Feb 18 15:42:08 monteur-HP-ProBook-650-G1 systemd-resolved[526]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Feb 18 15:42:08 monteur-HP-ProBook-650-G1 systemd-resolved[526]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Feb 18 15:42:43 monteur-HP-ProBook-650-G1 NetworkManager[717]: <warn>  [1613659363.1767] dhcp4 (enp0s25): request timed out
Feb 18 15:42:43 monteur-HP-ProBook-650-G1 NetworkManager[717]: <info>  [1613659363.1768] dhcp4 (enp0s25): state changed unknown -> timeout
Feb 18 15:42:43 monteur-HP-ProBook-650-G1 NetworkManager[717]: <info>  [1613659363.1770] device (enp0s25): state change: ip-config -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavailable', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 18 15:42:43 monteur-HP-ProBook-650-G1 NetworkManager[717]: <warn>  [1613659363.1805] device (enp0s25): Activation: failed for connection 'Wired connection 1'
Feb 18 15:42:43 monteur-HP-ProBook-650-G1 NetworkManager[717]: <info>  [1613659363.1820] device (enp0s25): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 18 15:42:43 monteur-HP-ProBook-650-G1 avahi-daemon[712]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::b343:1d23:df15:7b48 on enp0s25.
Feb 18 15:42:43 monteur-HP-ProBook-650-G1 avahi-daemon[712]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface enp0s25.IPv6 with address fe80::b343:1d23:df15:7b48.
Feb 18 15:42:43 monteur-HP-ProBook-650-G1 avahi-daemon[712]: Interface enp0s25.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Feb 18 15:42:43 monteur-HP-ProBook-650-G1 NetworkManager[717]: <info>  [1613659363.1992] dhcp4 (enp0s25): canceled DHCP transaction
Feb 18 15:42:43 monteur-HP-ProBook-650-G1 NetworkManager[717]: <info>  [1613659363.1992] dhcp4 (enp0s25): state changed timeout -> done
Feb 18 15:42:43 monteur-HP-ProBook-650-G1 NetworkManager[717]: <info>  [1613659363.2037] policy: auto-activating connection 'Wired connection 1' (561d04b9-8c3a-36e4-aff4-86c737eb7cab)
Feb 18 15:42:43 monteur-HP-ProBook-650-G1 NetworkManager[717]: <info>  [1613659363.2045] device (enp0s25): Activation: starting connection 'Wired connection 1' (561d04b9-8c3a-36e4-aff4-86c737eb7cab)
Feb 18 15:42:43 monteur-HP-ProBook-650-G1 NetworkManager[717]: <info>  [1613659363.2047] device (enp0s25): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 18 15:42:43 monteur-HP-ProBook-650-G1 NetworkManager[717]: <info>  [1613659363.2050] device (enp0s25): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 18 15:42:43 monteur-HP-ProBook-650-G1 NetworkManager[717]: <info>  [1613659363.2057] device (enp0s25): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 18 15:42:43 monteur-HP-ProBook-650-G1 NetworkManager[717]: <info>  [1613659363.2060] dhcp4 (enp0s25): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Feb 18 15:42:43 monteur-HP-ProBook-650-G1 avahi-daemon[712]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface enp0s25.IPv6 with address fe80::b343:1d23:df15:7b48.
Feb 18 15:42:43 monteur-HP-ProBook-650-G1 avahi-daemon[712]: New relevant interface enp0s25.IPv6 for mDNS.
Feb 18 15:42:43 monteur-HP-ProBook-650-G1 avahi-daemon[712]: Registering new address record for fe80::b343:1d23:df15:7b48 on enp0s25.*.
Feb 18 15:42:45 monteur-HP-ProBook-650-G1 systemd-resolved[526]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Feb 18 15:42:49 monteur-HP-ProBook-650-G1 systemd-resolved[526]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Feb 18 15:42:53 monteur-HP-ProBook-650-G1 systemd-resolved[526]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Feb 18 15:42:53 monteur-HP-ProBook-650-G1 systemd-resolved[526]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
```

Comment: Please add the relevant output of `journalctl -f` when you connect your ethernet port.

Comment: Well you don't have any IP address set on the ethernet interface. Try to set it manually using ip a a 192.168.x.x/24 dev ep0s25

Comment: Thank you for your posts, in mean time I made some discoveries. On a laptop installed the same version of Ubuntu, booting from internal hdu the network port is functioning.

Comment: @BulletBob, please take some time to read the log.